# How to create custom search box with suggestions (in a custom list) using data from google place API?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I need to build a custom place picker which would be shown in an activity, I am building an edit text in which we could implement a text watcher and once user puts place text on it, display the corresponding places from google place. In short i just want to build a customized google place API auto text complete.

Comment: you can use `AutoCompleteTextView`, and populate it with data received from places API

Comment: I am not able to understand how to do this, do you have a link to the code on how I can implement it ? to refer.

Comment: Also most of answers I have found use the deprecated place API methods.

Comment: what about official documentations? It has the guide how to use it

Comment: So um if i use the AutoCompleteTextView the resultant response only sends out the place names, is there a way to get lat longs as well of the same ?

Comment: you have to populate `AutoCompleteTextView` manually, it does not send anything anywhere